# How to handle Exceptions in Cypress in a similar way we did in selenium

Tags: cypress

In selenium we can handle exception. If any exception occur in any testcase it will then jump onto next testcase we can did in selenium. But i an confused that how can we did this in Cypress. Taking below example

```
 it('Test Case 1', function () {
        cy.visit('https://habitica.com/login')
        cy.get('form').find('input[id="usernameInput"]').click().type("username")
        cy.get('form').find('input[id="passwordInput"]').click().type("password")
        **cy.get('.btn-info').click()** 
        cy.get('.modal-dialog').find('button[class="btn btn-warning"]').click()
        cy.get('.start-day').find('button').click({force:true})
    })

 it('Test Case 2', function () {
        cy.visit('https://habitica.com/login')
        cy.get('form').find('input[id="usernameInput"]').click().type("username")
        cy.get('form').find('input[id="passwordInput"]').click().type("password")
        cy.get('.btn-info').click() 
        cy.get('.modal-dialog').find('button[class="btn btn-warning"]').click()
        cy.get('.start-day').find('button').click({force:true})
    })
```

Lets say browser unable to find click element (Highlighted with bold) in testcase 1 then it will jump onto Testcase 2.

How can we do it in Cypress?

Please help me on this

Exceptions like Unable to fine element or similar others.

Other than this example how can we handle exceptions or error.

Comment: you can find answers here [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#cy)

Answer (score 1):

Although Cypress team is saying that we need to avoid conditional test as much as possible (and maybe a need to change your approach). However, in you case, you can include a conditional test:

```
cy.get('.btn-info').then((body) => {
 if (body.length > 0) { // continues if the element exists
    cy.get('.btn-info').click();
    cy.get('.modal-dialog').find('button[class="btn btn-warning"]').click()
    cy.get('.start-day').find('button').click({force:true})
 } // if the above condition is not met, then it skips this the commands and moves to the next test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for your response. Please have a look at this. I have used your code. "'.btn-info'" does not exist so exception occur which is fine. but problem is it do not move onto else statement. I mean If statement gets failed then it must execute else but it do not. Why it is doing so?

```
      it('First Test Case', function() {

      cy.visit('http://pb.folio3.com:9000/admin/#/login');

      cy.get('.btn-info').then((body) => {    // **THIS ELEMENT NOT EXIST**
        if (body.length > 0) { // continues if the element exists
           cy.get('.btn-info').click();
           cy.get('.modal-dialog').find('button[class="btn btn-warning"]').click()
           cy.get('.start-day').find('button').click({force:true})
        } 
else
{
        **cy.visit('https://www.facebook.com/');**
}

       });


       it('Second Test Case', function() {
        cy.visit('https://www.google.com/');

      })
```